# Calling a subclass from mainclass

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I have a base class `Board_S` and `10` other classes that inherit the base `Board_S` class.

I have an object for `Board_S` which calls the `Board_S` class and its function which should call one more function from a specific sub class.

I am getting the error : `Class does not name a type`;

How to do I call the subclass function from this main Class.

Please Help

Comment: Could you share your code??

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this correctly is to declare a virtual function in your base class and implement it in your derived class.

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    virtual ~A() {}

    virtual void func() {}

    void CallFunc() { func(); }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() {}
    virtual ~B() {}

    virtual void func() {} // overrides it
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    A* pB = new B;

    a.CallFunc(); // will call the base class version of func()
    pB->CallFunc(); // will call the derived class version of func()

    delete pB;
}
```

If you don't need the function overridden in a derived class (and the function isn't declared as a pure virtual function), you do not override it.